# Free running tracker for Android

Tags: gratis, android, sport, gps-tracking

Is there any free/open sport tracking app that allows:

1. Heart rate measurements - using some gear hardware like miband etc.
2. Has a voice assistant speaking about pace etc.
3. Has a personal training system (with intervals etc.)

I am looking for an app that is free and is a combination of Mi Fit (multiple charts and frequent heart rate measurements) and Endomondo (voice assistant and coach, goals, etc.).

Comment: You used the tag [tag:gps-tracking], but your question doesn’t seem to say something about sich a feature. Did you add this tag intentionally and the app needs to track your position via GPS?

Answer (score 1):

[RunnerUp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.runnerup) is a free and open source sports tracker for Android with no user tracking, no ads or in app purchases.

[image]

It doesn't forcibly use any online services nor require signing in, and can export your data in a variety of formats for offline use and upload to other devices.

It can optionally be configured to upload your data to popular online tracking services, if you like.

It has audio cues, stats, graphs, maps, auto laps and configurable time or distance intervals.

It integrates with a variety of third party heart rate monitors.